# Web tokens management

Tags: php, security, csrf

I am building website in PHP. To every `form` tag I add `token` field to prevent CSRF attacks.

In each page I am creating a random string and store it in the session.

```
$_SESSION['form1_token'] = hash('sha512', uniqid(null, true));
```

HTML:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form1_token']; ?>" />
    ....
</form>
```

Then I check the value in the server side and delete the token from the session.

It works fine, but what can I do if the user navigate to another page without sending the form? The token will never be deleted.

Time limitation is not good, because my web page supposed to run for a long time, and require refreshment could be annoying.
So I thought about sending request in the `unload` event to delete the session. But users with a little bit knowledge in web, can with every browser to delete the event.

How can I manage the tokens correctly?

Comment: Have a look at [CSRF protection: do we have to generate a token for every form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8655817/53114)

Answer (score 0):

Use a time limit. Set it to something long (like a day). If the page is designed to sit there for longer than that, then send an Ajax request on a timer to a script that extends the lifetime of the token in the database.