# How long should the lifetime of a CSRF token be?

Tags: security, session, csrf

Should I have short lifetime for my CSRF token or can I have it last for the length of the session?

Comment: if it lasts the life of the session, then if it gets stolen, it case be abused for the life of that session... it should be a one-time-use

Comment: No @MarcB. What makes a CSRF token special is that it's not a cookie and so not sent automatically on every request. Session lifespan is fine. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539335/721263) below got it right.

Comment: Related question: [CSRF protection: do we have to generate a token for every form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8655817/53114)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token is not an access token and does not have a lifetime like bearer tokens do. They are generated using session information.

`csrf_token = HMAC(session_token, application_secret)`

CSRF adds additional information to your requests that lets the server verify the requests comes from an authorized location.

It only affects requests where the authorization info is sent automatically by the browser (cookie auth or basic/digest scheme)

Comment: They don't have to be session-related. Could be per-request as well.

Comment: Why does the generation include session information? Why not using a completely random value? And it is authentication info and not authorization info.

Comment: Yes, keep your session ID protected. Don't expose it unnecessarily.

Comment: Using your session ID as input to an HMAC calculation does not expose the ID itself. You can't get the ID from the HMAC.

Comment: I know this is several years late, but I've seen applications where "sessions" are not a native part of the programming language, such as Node.js. If one wishes to use "sessions", you have to install third-party libraries. Hence, short TTL may be the only option regarding security if no session changing data is available that should be used instead of TTL. I'm no security expert, so please correct me if I'm wrong.