# How to use OWASP CSRF Protector to every POST request via AJAX?

Tags: csrf-protection, owasp

Hello stackoverflow community,

I searched in google a method to protect my website HTTP POST requests from csrf attacks and i found the OWASP CSRF Protector project, i place the page link in case someone don't know what is : [click here](https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP/wiki/How-to-use) to check in git reposity. I followed the guide as the author of the above page explains but doesnt seems to work cause i cant make an ajax request with success and i don't have either an error message to understand what goes wrong.

To conclude, i downloaded the OWASP CSRF Protector library, i placed to my config file a `CSRFP_TOKEN` and also in each php page the following code at the begin of each page:

```
<php    
    include_once __DIR__ .'/libs/csrf/csrfprotector.php';

    //Initialise CSRFGuard library
    csrfProtector::init();

?>
```

Does anyone know what else i should do, maybe attach this csrf token to each form, creating a `SESSION` and how to do something like that.

PS-> The token can be static or do i need to change it dynamically

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps here to use CSRF Protector:

https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP/wiki/How-to-use

Please notice that, you need to edit the jsUrl in the config.php file to point to the path where you placed your csrfprotector.js

**Example**
"jsUrl" => "http://localhost/**YOU_PATH_TO_XCSRF**/xcsrf/vendor/owasp/csrf-protector-php/js/csrfprotector.js"

You can do a per session token or a per form token, see the answers in this question for more details:
[CSRF protection: do we have to generate a token for every form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655817/csrf-protection-do-we-have-to-generate-a-token-for-every-form)